# How to write a pivot/crosstab query in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I need to write a query for SQL Server. I have a table employee along with the fields listed below (please see Employee Table in bold). I want to get the results shown below (please see Result in bold).

**Employee Table:**

```
Name
Age
Salary
Employee Type
Employed Date
```

**Employee Data:**

```
Name        Age   Salary      Employee_Type   Date_Hired
Employee 1  24    24,000.00   Staff           January 15, 2009
Employee 2  33    32,000.00   Staff           February 1, 2005
Employee 3  23    75,000.00   Consultant      March 20, 2002
```

**Result:**

```
          Employee 1           Employee 2           Employee 3
Age           24                    33                  23
Salary        24,000.00             32,000.00           75,000.00
Employee_Type Staff                 Staff               Consultant
Date_Hired    January 15, 2009      February 1, 2005    March 20, 2002
```

Comment:  It can be done but as you add employees you add columns and SQL isn't designed for that without dynamic SQL. Personally, I'd do this in a report or client code or Access/Excel pivots

Comment: gbn- that is a sample only. It will not takes hundreds of records for Employee. It has a maximum of 10 records only. I replaced my original table into Employee in this question to have a clear perspective. ;)

Comment: @Ocaso Protal- If I put it here will you solved it? I try to put this question just to get some idea/s or another approach to solved this problem.

Comment: I'm not a pivot expert, so I will probably not answer your question. **But** experience shows that you will get an answer when you post what you tried so far. Maybe you have only one minor error in your code.

Comment: ok, thank you. So kept on eye on this question, maybe somebody will answer this one. Or I will post my answer here once I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create Table #Employee (Name Varchar(20), Age TinyInt, Salary SmallMoney, EmployeeType Varchar(20), EmployedDate Date)

Insert Into #Employee
Select 'Employee 1', 24, 24000.00, 'Staff', '01/15/2009' Union all 
Select 'Employee 2', 33, 32000.00, 'Staff', '02/01/2005' Union All 
Select 'Employee 3', 23, 75000.00, 'Consultant', '03/20/2002'

Declare @Names As Varchar(Max), @strSQL Varchar(Max)
Select @Names = Stuff((Select ',' + QuoteName(Name) From #Employee Order by Name For XML Path('')), 1, 1, '')
Set @strSQL = ';With CTE As (Select Name, FieldName, FieldValue From (Select Name, Convert(Varchar(20), Age) As Age, Convert(Varchar(20), Salary) As Salary, Convert(Varchar(20), EmployeeType) As EmployeeType, Convert(Varchar(20), EmployedDate, 101) As EmployedDate From #Employee )As p UnPivot (FieldValue For FieldName In (Age, Salary, EmployeeType, EmployedDate) )AS unpvt) Select * From CTE Pivot (Max(FieldValue) For Name in (' + @Names + ')) As Pvt'
print @strSQL
Execute (@strSQL)

Drop Table #Employee
```

thanks to Arbi Baghdanian, :)

Comment: Any other solution is highly appreciated.:)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of doing it. The UNPIVOT is used to transfer the column names to rows and then a standard grouping by that ColumnName (which is now a row) is used to pivot the name/value combination for each of the employee. Please note that when using unpivot the columns should be of the same data type, this is why cast and convert are present. The only downside of this approach is that the employee names are hardcoded, but this is always a problem unless dynamic pivoting is used instead. However, since you mentioned that you only have but about 10 employees to corsstab, it should not be a problem. Here is the script:

```
select
    unp.ColumnName,
    max(case when Name = 'Employee 1' then Value else null end) [Employee 1],
    max(case when Name = 'Employee 2' then Value else null end) [Employee 2],
    max(case when Name = 'Employee 3' then Value else null end) [Employee 3]
    from 
    (
        select 
            Name, cast(Age as varchar(20)) Age, 
            cast(Salary as varchar(20)) Salary, 
            cast(Employee_Type as varchar(20)) Employee_Type,
            convert(varchar(20), Employed_Date, 106) Employed_Date  
            from dbo.Employee
    ) src
    unpivot 
    (
        Value for ColumnName in (
            [Age], [Salary], [Employee_Type], [Employed_Date])
    ) unp
    group by unp.ColumnName;

-- the above produces something like this for 
-- the data consistent with the sample in question:

ColumnName           Employee 1           Employee 2           Employee 3
-------------------- -------------------- -------------------- -----------
Age                  24                   33                   23
Employed_Date        15 Jan 2009          01 Feb 2005          20 Mar 2002
Employee_Type        Staff                Staff                Consultant
Salary               24000.00             32000.00             75000.00
```

Thanks to Oleg. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare  @strSQL1 Varchar(Max)

Declare @Names1 As Varchar(Max)
Select @Names1 = Stuff((Select ',' + 'max(case when Name = '''+Name+'''then Value else null end)'+ QuoteName(Name) From Employee Order by Name For XML Path('')), 1, 1, '')
print @Names1

Set @strSQL1 = 'select
    unp.ColumnName,'+@Names1+ ' from 
    (
        select 
            Name, cast(Age as varchar(20)) Age, 
            cast(Salary as varchar(20)) Salary, 
            cast(Employee_Type as varchar(20)) Employee_Type,
            convert(varchar(20), Date_Hired, 106) Date_Hired
            from dbo.Employee
    ) src
    unpivot 
    (
        Value for ColumnName in (
            [Age], [Salary], [Employee_Type], Date_Hired)
    ) unp
    group by unp.ColumnName; ' 

print @strSQL1
Execute (@strSQL1)
```

Another dynamic solution-upgraded Oleg's solution